# SQL ISNULL equivalent in ormlite

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

is there an equivalent of `ISNULL` in SQL for `OrmLite`?

I tried adding

```
[Default(typeof(int),"-1")]
```

to my class model, but had no luck..

I'm working with `MVC5` and `C#`

Comment: `ISNULL(something,-1)` isn't a default. It's a function call equivalent to `somethingNullable ?? -1`.

Comment: I know it's not a default. But if ORMLite finds a NULL field on that integer field on the db, it falls back to the default int value, which is 0. This is what I think, and that's why I'm looking for a default...

Comment: If you don't want to specify a default in your table, inspect the value in your property's setter and replace it with -1 if it's null

Comment: that's not what happens. If your property is an `int` and the data is null, any ORM would have to throw or return **the type's default value**. For ints, that's 0. This has nothing to do with the `Default` attribute

Comment: Oh, I'm going to try that and get back to you in a moment!

Comment: Well, I think I solved using int? instead of int, so I can know when I get null. It wasn't very clear from my post, but I wanted to use -1 just to know if the value was null in the DB... but you pointed me to the right direction anyway :)

Comment: ServiceStack isn't free. The source code is available as open source but ... [no docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/DataAnnotations/DefaultAttribute.cs). If you [search for DefaultValue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=+DefaultValue&type=) in the source you'll see the attribute is used to generate column definitions. The attribute specifies what the default constraint of a column is (as expected), not the replacement value to use instead of NULL

Comment: As for your comment, you *do* know that the value was null in the database, because you used `int?` and it's null. If you don't really want to replace nulls, just use and `int?` property